# Proving Weierstrass sine representation mass bound: $\inf_n \sup_{|w| \geq m} |s_n(w)| \leq 4^{1-m}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality

If one defines
$$ s_n(w):=\frac{\sin\pi w}{\pi w}\prod_{j=1}^n\left( 1-\frac{w^2}{j^2}\right)^{-1}=\prod_{j=n+1}^\infty\left( 1-\frac{w^2}{j^2}\right),$$
how may one show that, for every $m \geq 0,$
$$\inf_n \sup_{|w| \geq m} |s_n(w)| \leq 4^{1-m}\hspace{2.8pt}?$$